# Better to mix subs in headphones or through monitors?

Tags: headphones, monitors, sub-bass

When making sub basses for a rubbish trap song is it better to mix through speakers or headphones?

I have BX5 M-AUDIO monitors and Audio Technica ATH-M30 headphones.

Answer (score 0):

You'll ideally be mixing to a reference track. Play your reference track through either speakers or headphones - whatever sounds better to you. Get your ears tuned to the mix environment, then get to work on your trap song. Headphones vs Speakers is generally always going to be personal preference. Yes - most professional mixers will be working in a treated environment with tuned speakers, but that's not always the case these days. You work with what you've got and what works.